# gcc compile dpdk error: no such instruction vextracti128

Tags: c, linux, gcc, dpdk

In Centos 6.2, I used gcc 4.8.0 to compile DPDK code (dpdk-stable-17.05.2), meet a compile error.
compile command:
*make install T=x86_64-native-linuxapp-gcc*

output:

```
== Build lib/librte_eal/linuxapp/eal    
  CC eal.o    
  CC eal_hugepage_info.o    
  CC eal_memory.o   
/tmp/ccZMmoL5.s: Assembler messages:    
/tmp/ccZMmoL5.s:1189: Error: no such instruction: `vextracti128 $0x1,%ymm0,internal_config+192(%rip)'   
/tmp/ccZMmoL5.s:1192: Error: no such instruction: `vextracti128 $0x1,%ymm0,internal_config+248(%rip)'    
/tmp/ccZMmoL5.s:1196: Error: no such instruction: `vextracti128 $0x1,%ymm0,internal_config+304(%rip)'
```

Also tried gcc 4.9.0 and dpdk-17.11, got the same compile error.
Does anyone meet the same error, or have a solution?

Added compile command with verbose output:
*make T=x86_64-native-linuxapp-gcc V=1*

output:

```
== Build lib/librte_eal/linuxapp/eal
gcc -Wp,-MD,./.eal_memory.o.d.tmp  -m64 -pthread  -march=native -DRTE_MACHINE_CPUFLAG_SSE -DRTE_MACHINE_CPUFLAG_SSE2 -DRTE_MACHINE_CPUFLAG_SSE3 -DRTE_MACHINE_CPUFLAG_SSSE3 -DRTE_MACHINE_CPUFLAG_SSE4_1 -DRTE_MACHINE_CPUFLAG_SSE4_2 -DRTE_MACHINE_CPUFLAG_PCLMULQDQ -DRTE_MACHINE_CPUFLAG_AVX -DRTE_MACHINE_CPUFLAG_RDRAND -DRTE_MACHINE_CPUFLAG_AVX2  -I/root/dpdk/dpdk-stable-17.05.2/build/include -include /root/dpdk/dpdk-stable-17.05.2/build/include/rte_config.h -I/root/dpdk/dpdk-stable-17.05.2/lib/librte_eal/linuxapp/eal/include -I/root/dpdk/dpdk-stable-17.05.2/lib/librte_eal/common -I/root/dpdk/dpdk-stable-17.05.2/lib/librte_eal/common/include -W -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -Wmissing-prototypes -Wmissing-declarations -Wold-style-definition -Wpointer-arith -Wcast-align -Wnested-externs -Wcast-qual -Wformat-nonliteral -Wformat-security -Wundef -Wwrite-strings -O3    -o eal_memory.o -c /root/dpdk/dpdk-stable-17.05.2/lib/librte_eal/linuxapp/eal/eal_memory.c 
/tmp/ccUFBnoh.s: Assembler messages:
/tmp/ccUFBnoh.s:1188: Error: no such instruction: `vextracti128 $0x1,%ymm0,internal_config+192(%rip)'
/tmp/ccUFBnoh.s:1191: Error: no such instruction: `vextracti128 $0x1,%ymm0,internal_config+248(%rip)'
/tmp/ccUFBnoh.s:1195: Error: no such instruction: `vextracti128 $0x1,%ymm0,internal_config+304(%rip)'
make[5]: *** [eal_memory.o] Error 1
```

Comment: You should try to do the build with verbosity turned on. Also, just do a `make T=x86_64-native-linuxapp-gcc` (without the install) to make sure it builds locally

Comment: Even GCC 4.9 is really old and unmaintained. Current GCC is [GCC 7](https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-7/) (in november 2017)  and GCC 8 goes out in a few weeks. Try to install at least GCC6 on your system, perhaps by building the compiler from its source code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a gcc 4.8.0 bug (see https://github.com/nouiz/Theano/commit/04cb385df37c669b2f449d34d34d9835085cbce9) for a similar issue that was discovered in another software.

You can get around it a couple of different ways.

1) Force no-avx2 with `gcc -mno-avx2`. the vextracti128 is an avx2 feature so the compiler won't use this optimization.

OR

2) Upgrade your gcc to 4.8.5

Comment: If gcc 4.8.5 can work, should my gcc 4.9.0 works? In my case, gcc 4.9.0 have the same compile error as gcc 4.8.0. 
I installed gcc 4.9.0 by compile its code.

[root@localhost ~]# gcc -v    
Using built-in specs.    
COLLECT_GCC=gcc    
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/local/libexec/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/4.9.0/lto-wrapper    
Target: x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu    
Configured with: ../gcc-4.9.0/configure --enable-checking=release --enable-languages=c,c++ --disable-multilib    
Thread model: posix    
gcc version 4.9.0 (GCC)

Comment: I am not sure, can you please try compiling the software with `gcc -mno-avx2` in the CFLAGS

Comment: A little bit of digging shows that gcc 4.x series has broken avx/avx2 support. If you have the ability to compile a new gcc, use gcc-7.x series

Comment: It turns out add -mno-avx2 in the CFLAGS can solve this problem. Thanks to Ahmed's kindly help!

Comment: With suitable gcc installed, the problem will also solved. Install gcc 4.9.2 via devtoolset-3 is OK for me. My previous gcc is local build by code, the local build gcc is OK for others projects, but seems have the problem with this.

Comment: yes the devtoolset-3 (RHEL/CENTOS I'm guessing) will have the appropriate patches backported.